# Here/away migration stats are swapped

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, migrated-questions

This appears to be an issue everywhere, but I'll use [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/admin/posts/migrated/stats) as an example:

[image]

The page shows that there have been 2 migrations to EE from Physics, 8 from DIY, etc. when in reality it's the other way around. Eight questions have been migrated from EE to DIY in the past 90 days.

Likewise, five questions were migrated *from* Stack Overflow *to* EE, and so on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eeeeeeeeeeeeek:-) Fixing it...

---

This is fixed in dev and will be out in the next release in a few minutes.

Comment: You can't smile *and* eeek at the same time. Eeek requires a worried face.

Comment: I needed to add a disproportionate number of "e" for the character limit, so I needed to soften the impact

Comment: @animuson - Sklivvz has been doing localization. The face is correct.

Comment: I'm curious how these got swapped in the first place. Last time I saw them they were fine.

Comment: @Manishearth - localization. It's always localization.

Comment: Well, while doing localization I tried to make some great code awesomer, but it was so fresh and legible that I got it the other way round. Of course, the bug is not so easy to spot without a test, which I didn't have...

Comment: @Oded Wait a sec. Why would you localize _arrows_? Or does it have to do with LTR?

Comment: @Sklivvz Ah, I see :)

Comment: @Manishearth: that answers my next question: Has my migration analysis over the years been plagued by _bad data_?  ;)

Comment: Technically there is the "xx% rejected" text localized in that bit of the code

Comment: @JonEricson Yeah, when I heard of this first in TL I felt guilty for being angry at Math.SE for throwing crap over the fence (at the same time getting a migration path to math because we were pretty good at picking what to migrate).

Comment: @Manishearth - LTR? Shudder. My very first web work was in Hebrew. Before proper bidi algorithms existed in browsers. I can tell you that our current L10n efforts don't even try to go there, and I fear for my sanity the day we do.